# How to disable logs in playwright .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, logging, playwright

Im using playwright v1.29.0 , i can't find a way to disable logs. Is there any methods or settings i could use ? As the logs make the hard disk full on the server, that's why i want to disable them.

I tried to put a timeout default to 0. But, its not a proper way to do this and for my tests that's not correct.

```
IBrowser browser = driver.Firefox.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
                    {
                        Headless = false,
                        ExecutablePath = browserPath,
                        Timeout = 0

                    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```